# Gulp: target to debug mocha tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a set of [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/) targets for running my mocha tests that work like a charm running through [gulp-mocha](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-mocha). Question: how do I debug my mocha tests running through gulp? I would like to use something like [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) to set break points in my src and test files to see what's going on. I am already able to accomplish this by calling node directly:

```
node --debug-brk node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js test
```

But I'd prefer a gulp target that wraps this for me, e.g.:

```
gulp.task('test-debug', 'Run unit tests in debug mode', function (cb) {
   // todo?
});
```

Ideas? I want to avoid a `bash` script or some other separate file since I'm trying to create a reusable `gulpfile` with targets that are usable by someone who doesn't know gulp.

Here is my current `gulpfile.js`

```
// gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  mocha = require('gulp-mocha'),
  gutil = require('gulp-util'),
  help = require('gulp-help');

help(gulp); // add help messages to targets

var exitCode = 0;

// kill process on failure
process.on('exit', function () {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    var msg = "gulp '" + gulp.seq + "' failed";
    console.log(gutil.colors.red(msg));
    process.exit(exitCode);
  });
});

function testErrorHandler(err) {
  gutil.beep();
  gutil.log(err.message);
  exitCode = 1;
}

gulp.task('test', 'Run unit tests and exit on failure', function () {
  return gulp.src('./lib/*/test/**/*.js')
    .pipe(mocha({
      reporter: 'dot'
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) {
      testErrorHandler(err);
      process.emit('exit');
    });
});

gulp.task('test-watch', 'Run unit tests', function (cb) {
  return gulp.src('./lib/*/test/**/*.js')
    .pipe(mocha({
      reporter: 'min',
      G: true
    }))
    .on('error', testErrorHandler);
});

gulp.task('watch', 'Watch files and run tests on change', function () {
  gulp.watch('./lib/**/*.js', ['test-watch']);
});
```

Comment: maybe use childprocess.exec? http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: @BrianGlaz that's a good idea. The only downside is that you don't get output from the process until the task is complete instead of as-you-go. Is there a way to do this while getting progressive output to stdout?

Comment: Check out child_process.spawn() http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options. it's very similar but acts as an event emitter letting you attach callbacks. Check the link for examples.

Comment: Nice, I think that will work great. Now just create an answer out of that and you've got some rep coming your way ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With some guidance from @BrianGlaz I came up with the following task. Ends up being rather simple. Plus it pipes all output to the parent's `stdout` so I don't have to handle `stdout.on` manually:

```
  // Run all unit tests in debug mode
  gulp.task('test-debug', function () {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    spawn('node', [
      '--debug-brk',
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js'),
      'test'
    ], { stdio: 'inherit' });
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Node's `Child Process` class to run command line commands from within a node app. In your case I would recommend [childprocess.spawn()](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options). It acts as an event emitter so you can subscribe to `data` to retrieve output from `stdout`. In terms of using this from within gulp, some work would probably need to be done to return a stream that could be piped to another gulp task.

Comment: I assume you mean `childprocess.spawn()`?

Comment: I appreciate your guidance but I don't feel like I can ultimately accept this as the correct answer since it doesn't answer the question: providing a way to do this via a gulp task.